# CardView background changing when changing visibility?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, visibility, android-cardview

I have to show the `CardView` when taping the **Tap to edit text** `TextView` and tapping outside will hide the `CardView`. I have tried to switch `CardView` background to transparent and white for doing that and it isn't working. Then I tried to put both `EditText` which contains the letters and `CardView` in `FrameLayout` then hidden and shown the `CardView` but the `CardView` background style changing to transparent while did that. 
You can find my xml below. 
Tell me what is happening here please?

[image]

[image]

**XML**

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_2">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  android:id="@+id/cardView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="0dp"
  app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/box_radius"
  app:cardElevation="0dp"
  app:contentPadding="@dimen/margin_padding_2" />

<com.package.views.EditText
  android:id="@+id/note"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@null"
  android:cursorVisible="false"
  android:gravity="start"
  android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/margin_padding_1"
  android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_2"
  android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
  android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_5"
  app:textStyle="bold" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Code**

```
 private void controlView() {
        mCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mNote.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
        mNote.setCursorVisible(true);
        mNote.setSelection(mNote.length());
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
mCard.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: `mNote` is my `EditText` .I'm asking about `CardView`

Comment: I am glad it helped..!! :)

Answer (score 3):

To change color of **cardview** programatically you can use:

```
mCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

To do in XML

```
mCard:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Thank you for appriciation.@Stella

Comment: Both answers are seems correct but `janki gadhiya` had posted first so I'm accepting that & I have up voted your's too. Thank you

Comment: but I got the method `setCardBackgroundColor` :)